# MVC 5 ActionLink with Areas

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, actionlink, asp.net-mvc-areas

http://localhost:55201/SERVICES/customers/CALLME

**how to make this link using @Html.ActionLink**

Services is RouteArea, Customers is RoutePrefix and Customer is Controller

@Html.ActionLink("Click me", "CallMe",new { area = "Services"})
is this code right? its returning blank anchor.

```
[RouteArea("Services")]
[RoutePrefix("Customers")]

public class CustomerController : Controller
{
    [Route("~/Test")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Controller = "Customer";
        ViewBag.Action = "Index";
        return View("ActionName");
    }
    [Route("CallMe")]
    public string CallMeFunction()
    {
        return string.Format("CallMeFunction() invoked");
    }
  }
```